# DTAttributedLabel addAttribute not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring, nsmutableattributedstring, dtcoretext

I'm using DTAttributedLabel to decode some Html tags, and I want the label has two colors. It works fine when I was using UILabel, but the colors didn't show when I change it to DTAttributedLabel. Any help would be appreciated.

```
- (void)loadData:(ArticleModel *)data andTypeName:(NSString *)typeName{
    NSString *titleText;
    titleText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"[%@] %@", typeName, data.title];

    NSData *titleData = [titleText dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSMutableAttributedString *attrTitleStr = [[[[DTHTMLAttributedStringBuilder alloc]
                                 initWithHTML:titleData
                                 options:@{
                                           DTDefaultFontSize:@15
                                           }
                                 documentAttributes:nil]
                                generatedAttributedString] mutableCopy];

//here I add the colors
    [attrTitleStr addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:KCOLOR_BLUE_0066FF range:NSMakeRange(0, typeName.length + 2)];
    [attrTitleStr addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:KCOLOR_RED_6D2C1D range:NSMakeRange(typeName.length + 2, attrTitleStr.length - typeName.length - 2)];

    _titleLabel = [[DTAttributedLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 200)];
    [_titleLabel setAttributedString:attrTitleStr];}
```